# Joomla extensions often require modifying the core?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

People often say the extensibility of Drupal is better than Joomla.

Is this true that most Joomla extensions require modifying/hacking the core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve never used drupal so I cannot comment on that or compare.

But IMO, most joomla extensions **don`t require** modifiying/hacking core. My experience is that most of them install smoothly & easily from backend and they give plenty of configuration options. The look & feel is mostly configured with css / template files.(MVC architecture of the joomla also makes it easy to modify look & feel in case you are familiar with php.)

Still now & then, despite the 6000+ extensions in extensions.joomla.org, you cannot find any extension that matches your needs 100%. In that case you might need to hack/modify core, but this is not common.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So when some programmers say the Joomla's extensibility is bad, what do you think they are referring to?

Comment: To be honest, Ive never heard that and I dont know what are they referring to.

Comment: Joomla is pretty extensible. You need to bear in mind that Joomla is actually a framework (MVC). It's just that they have used the framework to build a CMS which is what most people think of Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything that would require hacking the core to accomplish. Take a look at extensions like K2 or Zoo or template frameworks like Gantry or Warp5, they do amazing things without touching a single core file. Joomla was written specifically to extend. It has a very good API that is pretty well documented. It's even getting better with 1.6 on the horizon.

Anyone who tells you that most Joomla extensions require hacking the core don't know what they are talking about.